# Facebook and flash - why doesn't facebook recognise that I have flash installed?

Tags: flash, facebook

For some reason when I try to upload photos to facebook from the website, it tells me I need to upgrade my flash player:

[image: facebook photo uploader]

I definitely have flash installed, as can be seen in the picture, and working fine in youtube etc.

[image: flash version]

My question is two-fold:

1) Does anyone know if this a problem with the version of flash I'm running, Ubuntu, or facebook itself? I get the same problem in Chrome and Firefox, so I know it's not the browser.

2) Is there a workaround or fix for this? As far as I can tell I'm running the very latest flash (on 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10) - but maybe that's the problem?

**Note:** Before everyone starts jumping up and down about using Shotwell or Digikam or some such to upload photos to facebook, I know about these (and do use Shotwell at times). Unfortunately Shotwell only lets you upload to a **Profile**, but doesn't (as far as I can tell) let you upload to a facebook **Page** of which I am an administrator, so I am forced do it through the website. Using the *simple uploader* as seen in the first picture is horribly slow and tedious, and often times out while uploading.

Of course if anyone knows of any alternate ways to upload to facebook **pages** I'd love to hear 'em!

Comment: @karthick87 - thanks but that's what I'm already using. I think the problem as suggested below is that facebook isn't yet recognising this version number. Cheers.

Comment: Same thing happens to me and I have Ubuntu 10.04 64bit, but thus far no solution to this issue.

Comment: I wonder why Facebook relies on Flash at all, is it really necessary? There is HTML 5 available, and there were so many security flaws in the previous versions that I avoid Flash even on my Windows machines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the [64bit beta](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/square/), and it looks like Facebook's version check code isn't accepting it. I get the same message in Facebook with that version of Flash on Firefox and Chrome. I don't think there's anything you can do but go back to the release version. Unless there's a Firefox extension that fakes plugin versions?

For what it's worth it's easier to disable different versions of a plugin on the fly in Chrome/ium on its about:plugins page.

Comment: Your link is to the 32bit version.

Comment: @Oli Thanks, corrected. Adobe's own link on http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ when you visit from a 64bit machine goes to the wrong page!

Answer (score 3):

You have a very new version of Flash. I thought I was using the latest version (10.2.161.23) and you're a whole minor version ahead... Which is odd.

You can see from the Adobe page that they think the latest version is 10.1.

I remember when I first started using Flash Player betas that some sites didn't recognise it as a new version (and thought I was out of date). I guess Facebook could be doing this.

Comment: I'm using the 64-bit package installed from the ppa mentioned in the comment above (from karthick87), which was recently updated to the version number I'm currently running. I've actually noticed flash videos running smoother lately, so might be worth the update.